# DISTINCT and ORDER

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, arel

Here's one tricky relation:

I'm having the following AR relation:

```
# Doctor
has_many :patients, through: :meetings, uniq: true
has_many :meetings
```

@doctor.patients works as expected, nothing spectacular there. But now I'd like to get the patients for a doctor ordered by the created_at of the assignment (newest first).

```
# Doctor
has_many :patients, through: :meetings, uniq: true, order: 'meetings.created_at DESC'
has_many :meetings
```

Now that doesn't work (on Postgres 9): "ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list". Alright let's do that:

```
# Doctor
has_many :patients, through: :meetings, select: 'DISTINCT patients.*, meetings.created_at', order: 'meetings.created_at DESC'
has_many :meetings
```

This works again, but patients are not unique anymore since the DISTINCT is working on the entire SELECT clause.

Is it possible to fetch all patients for a doctor with the duplicate patients removed but still ordere by the newest meeting of each patient in one JOINed query?

Thanks for your hints!

**UPDATE:**

Using Oliver's hint I've updated the relation as follows:

```
# Doctor
has_many :patients,
  through: :assignments,
  select: 'patients.*, MAX(assignments.created_at) AS last_assignment', 
  group: 'patients.id',
  order: 'last_assignment DESC',
  counter_sql: proc { "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT patients.id) FROM patients INNER JOIN assignments ON patients.id=assignments.patient_id WHERE assignments.doctor_id=#{id}" }
```

The separate counter_sql apears to be necessary since Rails replaces the entire select clause to build the SQL for #count.

Any way to make this less bulky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
    MAX(meetings.created_at)
```

everywhere. Like this, you get unique patient records, even if patients have several meetings. My example will select the latest meeting. Use `MIN(meetings.created_at)` if you prefer to select the first one instead.

Comment: Thanks araqnid, added some clarifications.

Comment: I've worked your hint into the question. Using MIN() in the AR relation requires a few more additions, but it works. (I'll accept your answer shortly.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
has_many :patients, 
    through: :meetings, 
    order: 'meetings.created_at DESC', 
    conditions: 'row_number() over(partition by meetings.doctor_id, meetings.patient_id) order by meetings.created_at desc) = 1'
```

another attempt:

```
has_many :patients, 
    through: :meetings, 
    order: 'max(meetings.created_at) DESC', 
    group: 'patients.*',
    select: 'patients.*'
```

Comment: This doesn't work: ERROR: window functions not allowed in WHERE clause